# How to get current (add) button when user click on remove button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my script is that when user click on add button then add button hide and remove button show in next field. which is perfect. now i want when user click on remove button then show previous add button in current field automatically.

Please tell me how to do this.

Here is my script:-

```
 ! function(a) {
"use strict";
a(function() {
    var b = a(".wpcf7-field-groups");
    b.length && (b.each(function() {
        a(this).data("group-model", a(this).find(".wpcf7-field-group").eq(0).clone())
    }), a("body").on("wpcf7-field-groups/change", ".wpcf7-field-groups", function() {
        var b = a(this).find(".wpcf7-field-group");
        b.each(function(b) {
            a(this).find(".wpcf7-field-group-remove").toggle(b > 0);

            var c = b + 1;
            a(this).find("[name]").each(function() {

                var b = a(this),
                    d = b.closest(".wpcf7-form-control-wrap"),
                    e = b.attr("name"),
                    f = e.indexOf("[]") > -1,
                    g = e.replace("[]", ""),
                    h = g.replace(/__[0-9]*/, "") + "__" + c;
                d.length && !d.hasClass(h) && d.removeClass(g).addClass(h), h += f ? "[]" : "", b.attr("name", h)
            })
        }), a(this).find(".wpcf7-field-group-count").val(b.length)
    }), b.trigger("wpcf7-field-groups/change"), a("body").on("click", ".wpcf7-field-group-add, .wpcf7-field-group-remove", function(e) {
        var b = a(this),
            c = b.closest(".wpcf7-field-groups");
        if (b.hasClass("wpcf7-field-group-add")) {
              e.currentTarget.style.display = "none"; //ADD THIS LINE
            var d = c.data("group-model").clone();
            c.append(d), b.trigger("wpcf7-field-groups/added");
        } else b.trigger("wpcf7-field-groups/removed"), b.closest(".wpcf7-field-group").remove();

        return c.trigger("wpcf7-field-groups/change"), !1
    }))
})
}(jQuery);
```

Here is the live code link :- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqwORX

Please check and tell me how to fix this thanks alot in advance

Comment: it will be good if you put whole code instead of minified version

Comment: Thanks for your comment please check my full code with working https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqwORX

Comment: Hope this is help for you and you can help me for this thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```js
$("#remove").hide();
var num = 0;

$("#add").click(function() {
  $("#remove").show();
  num += 1;
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  element.setAttribute("id", num);
  element.setAttribute("class", "wpcf7-field-group");
  element.innerHTML = '<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><label>Test Held<br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap certification-held__1"><input type="text" name="certification-held__1" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></label></div><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><label>Date:<br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap certificate-date__1"><input type="date" name="certificate-date__1" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>';
  document.getElementById("results").appendChild(element);
});
$("#remove").click(function() {
  if ((num - 1) === 0) {
    $("#remove").hide();
  }
  document.getElementById(num).remove();
  num += -1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="results">
  
</div>

<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
```

Here, jQuery is setting up event listeners. When the user clicks either button, it toggle's the buttons. Here are the explanations of jQuery's functions:

### `.hide()`

Hides the selected element.

### `.show()`

Show the selected element.

### `.toggle()`

Toggles the selected element between hide and show.

`.toggle()` is the same as:

```
if ($(element).is(":visible")) {
    $(element).hide();
} else if ($(element).is(":hidden")) {
    $(element).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Will you please make this on my script.

Comment: Sorry! Your script is way too complicated. I've edited my answer to add your form.